# How to check user is a member of model object or not in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-permissions

I wrote this models in model.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
   MEMBERS_NUMBER = [
      (2, 'Two people'),
      (5, '3 to 5'),
      (10, '5 to 10'),
   ]
   group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   members = models.IntegerField(choices=MEMBERS_NUMBER)
   people = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', through='Membership', blank = True)
   summary = models.TextField(
      'Summary and indeas',
      max_length=500,
      help_text='Say what you want to do with your study or jub partner.'
   )
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

and

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpeg', upload_to = 'profile_pics', null=True, blank = True)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank = True)
```

and

```
class Membership(models.Model):
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  members = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then i created generic class-based view for every object of Group model but i want to limit access to only profiles in that Group object, this is my class-based view:

```
class GroupDetail(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.DetailView):
  model = models.Group
  context_object_name = 'group'
  template_name = 'projects/group_detail.html'

  def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.profile.group_set.filter(group_name='My-Django-Group')

  def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Group.objects.all()
```

The `test_func(self)` checks if user is member of 'My-Django-Group' then show the group details to user but i want to get the object name that we are in it, i tested this:

```
def test_func(self):  
return self.request.user.profile.group_set.filter(group_name=self.group.group_name)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the queryset with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class GroupDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
  model = models.Group
  context_object_name = 'group'
  template_name = 'projects/group_detail.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(
        people__user=self.request.user
    )
```

If the user is not a member of the group, they will receive a HTTP 404 response.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thanks, It's work with your guides. Is there any solution to handle this 404 response? for example redirect to home page and shows flash message?